# Incorrect syntax highlighting with non-ASCII characters

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

The C# highlighter (and possibly others) chokes on non-ASCII characters in class names, as can be seen in this post:

[Trouble with if circulating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265459/trouble-with-if-circulating)

[image]

EDIT: [Prettify bug report submitted](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=269).

Comment: Don't work with whoever wrote that.

Comment: [Submit a bug report to Prettify?](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

Comment: @animuson: done.

Answer (score 2):

[A comment in the code the default parser](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js?r=298#947) marks it as a known shortcoming in Prettify:

```
fallthroughStylePatterns.push(
    // TODO(mikesamuel): recognize non-latin letters and numerals in idents
    [PR_LITERAL,     /^@[a-z_$][a-z_$@0-9]*/i, null],
    [PR_TYPE,        /^(?:[@_]?[A-Z]+[a-z][A-Za-z_$@0-9]*|\w+_t\b)/, null],
    [PR_PLAIN,       /^[a-z_$][a-z_$@0-9]*/i, null],
...
```

By "non-latin," I think it really means non-ASCII. Fixing it would involve changing not just the statement quoted above, but *several* places where patterns like `a-z` or `a-zA-Z` appear. Prettify does some case-folding as part of its processing of regular expressions, and I imagine that contributes to making this a non-trivial problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that's a bug (and I agree with the comments...that's bad code as well), it's one that would need to be fixed on the prettify side.  Given this is the first time I've seen this though, I wouldn't wager they'll fix it unless they can do so in a way that doesn't suffer performance-wise for this edge case.